# Stop a Animated.loop with native driver - so it triggers the start callback

Tags: react-native

I am running a loop like this:

```
    const anim = new Animated.Value(0);

    const res = Animated.loop(
        Animated.timing(anim, {
            duration: 2000,
            toValue: 1,
            easing:Easing.inOut(Easing.linear),
            useNativeDriver: true,
            isInteraction: false
        })
    );
    res.start(e => console.log('anim stopped, e:'));

    setTimeout(()=>res.stop(), 5000); // does not trigger callback
    // setTimeout(()=>anim.stopAnimation(), 5000); // does not trigger callback
```

The animation runs, and loops properly. (animated value goes back to 0 at start of each loop).

And the animation stops, if i do either `res.stop()` or `anim.stopAnimation()`. But the start callback never triggers. I'm worried that something is still running and I might have a memory leak. Can you please advise on how to properly stop a native driver loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I couldn't find it in the documentation, there is an optional `onComplete` key available on the `AnimationConfig` type (I found it at the top of [Animation.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Animated/src/animations/Animation.js) in the repo). The log will now appear when your animation is stopped by adding the callback inside of your configuration:

```
const res = Animated.loop(
    Animated.timing(anim, {
        duration: 2000,
        toValue: 1,
        easing:Easing.inOut(Easing.linear),
        useNativeDriver: true,
        isInteraction: false,
        onComplete: (e) => console.log('anim stopped, e:') // New config option
    })
);
```

There's no guarantee that this won't be a breaking change in the future, but it seems like a pretty safe key name to stick with, so I don't see them refactoring that anytime soon.

As for your concern about the memory leak, the `Animated.loop` calls the `stop()` method of the child animation, so you should have no concerns there.

Comment: Awesome thank you! Doing `res.stop()` is same as doing `anim.stopAnimation()` correct?

Comment: It does appear to have the same effect on the `Animated.Value`, but I would encourage you to stick with `stop()` only because it's part of the documentation. `stopAnimation()` is part of `Animated.Value`'s prototype, but it isn't named in a way to indicate it as being private; so, if using it fits your needs better, I don't see a problem with implementing it.

Comment: Glad I could help!